# Centos: Not able to install pip

Tags: python, pip, python-install

I am totally new to python so I have no clue what's happening here.

When I do

```
which pip
/usr/bin/which: no pip in (/usr/local/bin/python:/usr/bin/python2:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
```

and then to install pip, when I do

```
sudo yum install python-pip
```

I get this

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, versionlock
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.myfahim.com
 * epel: kartolo.sby.datautama.net.id
 * extras: centos.myfahim.com
 * updates: centos.myfahim.com
Package python2-pip-8.1.2-5.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Can someone please help. It's very frustrating.

PS: Here are my python details
`which python`
/usr/local/bin/python

```
python --version
```

Python 2.6.6

Comment: Are u using centos version 5.x ?

Comment: I am using base64 centos-7

Comment: @user2991413 You mean x86_64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `python2-pip` RPM contains:

```
/usr/bin/pip
/usr/bin/pip2
/usr/bin/pip2.7
```

When there seems to be no `pip` in `/usr/bin`, check with:

`rpm -qV python2-pip`

for missing files and reinstall the RPM if necessary:

`yum reinstall python2-pip`

(Enabled `epel` repository is assumed.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably there can be problem with environment variable PATH.
You can try again with searching:

```
whereis pip
sudo updatedb
locate pip
```

take also look on

```
env | grep -i PATH
```

Or try again installing pip (again)

```
#adding epel repository https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories

yum -y update #it will update your repo package references
yum -y install python-pip # -y parameter says yes
```